# Is there a way to take a set of futures and block on them as a group while they execute in parallel?

Tags: clojure, future

I'd like to be able to wait on a group of functions.  I want them to execute in parallel, but block until the last future is done.   (I don't want them to execute sequentially, like with `(do @(future-1) @(future-2))`)

Something like

```clj
(declare long-running-fn-1)
(declare long-running-fn-2)

(let [results (wait-for-all
   (long-running-fn-1 ...)
   (long-running-fn-2 ...)]

     (println "result 1" (first results)
     (println "result 2" (second results))
```

Comment: They _always_ execute in parallel, even if you only request the results serially.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I don't think so.  this `(time (doall @(future (Thread/sleep 5000)) @(future (Thread/sleep 5000))))` takes 10 seconds, which leads me to believe it is blocking on the first future, then blocking on the second rather than executing both futures at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Futures are added to the same thread pool used for `send` the moment they're defined. As long as there are enough free threads in that pool (size of which will be slightly larger than your available number of CPU cores), calculation starts immediately.

The problem with `(doall @(future ...) @(future ...))` is that the second `future` isn't created until *after* the first one is deref'd.

Here's a slightly modified version of your code that defines *both* futures (starting their calculation) before deref'ing either of them; you'll see it takes only 5 seconds rather than 10:

```
(time
  (let [future-1 (future (Thread/sleep 5000))
        future-2 (future (Thread/sleep 5000))]
    [@future-1 @future-2]))
```

Comment: The use of `doall` is most likely wrong. It works for one or two args like this, that return null.

Comment: Moved to creating a vector.

Answer (score 3):

here is one more example, illustrating the parallel execution + sync dereferencing:

```
(letfn [(mk-fut [sleep-ms res]
          (future
            (Thread/sleep sleep-ms)
            (println "return" res "after" sleep-ms "ms")
            res))]
  (let [futures (mapv mk-fut
                      (repeatedly #(rand-int 2000))
                      (range 10))]
    (mapv deref futures)))

;; return 3 after 104 ms
;; return 8 after 278 ms
;; return 0 after 675 ms
;; return 6 after 899 ms
;; return 1 after 928 ms
;; return 2 after 1329 ms
;; return 9 after 1383 ms
;; return 4 after 1633 ms
;; return 5 after 1931 ms
;; return 7 after 1972 ms
;;=> [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

(the order of the output prints would differ between calls, while the resulting vector would be the same) You can see that all of the futures run in parallel, while generated and dereferenced in particular order.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pcalls` or `pvalues`:

```
test1.core=> (pcalls #(inc 1) #(dec 5))
(2 4)
test1.core=> (pvalues (inc 1) (dec 5))
(2 4)
```

Internally they use `pmap` which executes functions in parallel and return lazy sequence of results when all functions are processed.